# Error when assigning date in utc format to a field in mongodb from python code

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

In my python code i have the following line which stores the current date in UTC format in a field in a mongodb database:

```
s['metadata']['some_date'] = datetime.utcnow()
```

But on running the program, i get the following error :

> TypeError: 'unicode' object does not support item assignment

What is the wrong with my code and how to fix it ?

Please Help
Thank You

Comment: It's likely your `s` or `s['metadata']` is of string type.

Answer (score 2):

Either 's' or s['metadata'] is a string but not a dict....pdb is your friend.

Comment: If i do type(s['metadata']) it gives <type 'unicode'>. Does that have anything to do with the problem ?

Comment: *of course* - please think about what you are doing - why should be possible to assign something to a string?